# Set name of text file to variable with cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have directory `C:\Test\NewName.txt` and I want to take only the name `NewName` and put it in variable called `X`. The other problem is that I do not know what will be the name of the `.txt` file. I only know that it will be only one `.txt` file stored in the folder `Test`. Something like:

```
set X=C:\Test\NewName.txt
echo %X%
```

But it is not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are sure, there is only one `.txt` file:

```
for %%a in (C:\Test\*.txt) do set x=%%~fa
echo %x%
```

If there are more than one, it will pick the last one (alphabetically).

`%%~fa` is the full qualified filename (with drive, path, name, extension). If you need something different, see `for /?`

Note: this is the syntax for use in batchfiles. To use it on commandline, replace every `%%a` with `%a`

Comment: This is really good one and theoretically should be working but when i set it , it does not echo anything. In cmd shows for %a ... only with 1 % sign. May be I should be in specific directory with CD command or to set somewhere "" ? CMD shows only on the bottom ECHO is ON.